# Convert user-entered date from QString to QDate

Tags: c++, qt

I accept a date entered by the user, but the user can enter it in any format, for example `12/31/2014`, or `31 Dec 2014`, or `Dec 31 2014`, or `31.12.2014`. Is there a way to convert that to a `QDate` for any format that the user may have chosen?

I saw that `QDate::fromString()`, but it requires the format to be known in advance, and in my case I can't know how the user will enter it.

Comment: I believe you'll have to do some "recognizing" by yourself, perhaps with some regex

Comment: Yes, I have a feeling I'll have to code it on my own, too...

Comment: but is 02/01/11 equal to Jan 2 2011, Feb 1 2011 or Jan 11 2002 (all equally valid formats used around the world)

Comment: @ratchetfreak If you use / (slash), it is American style date, so it is mm/dd/yyyy, if you use . (dot), then it is German-style dd.mm.yyyy. So you can use / vs . to distinguish the order.

Comment: But in Belgium we use `/` and use the `dd/mm/yyyy` style

Comment: You could use a fixed format, have settings to choose the format from, or get the format from locale using [`QLocale::dateFormat`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlocale.html#dateFormat). Detecting the format from the input seems to be quite complicated, if not impossible as ratchet freak pointed out.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I didn't know that about Belgium, I had seen such dates sometimes, and I wondered if they are simply mistakes. If the day is above 12, you don't need to guess at the order anyway. For days below 12 it can be a problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing the UI of the application just use [QDateEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdateedit.html) widget.

> The QDateEdit class provides a widget for editing dates based on the
>   QDateTimeEdit widget.

And the displayed date is formatted according special widget property:

> displayFormat contains a string that is used to format the date
>   displayed in the widget.

Comment: You can't assume that, the user specifically asked for a QString->QDate conversion

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MarcoA., regular expression will work, but it's a case like "We had the issue and decided to solve it with regular expression. Now we have 2 issues: old one and not working correctly regular expression" :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, thanks, have updated it to contain more info.

Comment: @N1ghtLight Thanks, it had not occurred to me there's a special widget for that. So this is a possible solution. Still, sometimes you might get a QString date from some third-party control, so might question might be relevant for other people.

Comment: @sashoalm when you get it third party you should also have the format used known to you (or just go punch the guy who passes the date string)